# Dirichlet regression with repeated measures

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, dirichlet-distribution, compositional-data

My dependent variable is composition (proportions of a whole object), so I have found that a Dirichlet Regression would be a potential option. However, my study collects repeated measures. Can this type of model include repeated measures? I guess(?), each component could have estimates of fixed and random effects?